# How to migrate .delay tasks from Sidekiq to Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Given an existing rails app with background processes managed by [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

How can I migrate calls such as:

`Model.delay.some_action()`

From Sidekiq's syntax to Active Job's back-end agnostic syntax?

**Update:**

@craig.karminsky has pointed out the well-written [Sidekiq to Active Job Wiki Page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job). This page addresses mailers.

Old Sidekiq syntax:

`MyMailer.delay.send_message()`

Active Job syntax:

`MyMailer.send_message().deliver_later`

That's a good solution for mailers, but how can I migrate non-mailer calls to `.delay` such as:

`NotAMailer.delay.do_something()`

Answer (score 1):

Mike Perham, the creator of Sidekiq, has a very good [Wiki page](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job) up for just such a situation.

Comment: Great link to the docs, I've updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: It looked like `.perform_later` is the key for non-Mailer jobs in the Usage section on that page ... but there might be a better alternative I'm unaware of for sure!

Comment: Yeah `MyJob.perform_later` is great but requires a job to be defined. There maybe is no way around wrapping `Model.delay.some_action()` calls as Active Jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a gem for that on top of activejob: https://github.com/cristianbica/activejob-perform_later/. However the gem isn't very tested and this pattern is not a good one. Having code through your application that gets executed delay it will make your app hard to maintain and trigger all kind of bugs

Comment: What about your pattern don't you like?